# Implement callback from provider to component

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm looking to implement callback with Firebase in my Ionic2 app, means when it finish loading data then it go to component and "continue" the program and make things with data.

//course-page.ts

```
     ionViewDidLoad() {
   let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({});
    this.coursesA=this.coursesData.getCoursesList(this.department.id);
    if(this.coursesA){
      console.log("hello world");
      console.log(this.coursesA);
       loader.dismiss();

    }

  }
```

//course-data.ts

```
  public getCoursesList(departmentId:any):any
  {
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA');
  var listChild =[];
        rootRef.on('child_added', function (childData) {

          childData.forEach(function(childData2){
           listChild.push(childData2.val());          
            return false;
          })
        });
        callback(listChild); // cannot find name 'callback'

    }
  }
```

the 'course-page.ts' is my component and `course-data.ts` is the provider. I load data from Firebase. When it over i want to do something with the data.

I guess I do something wrong.

That's my Firebase structure

Comment: Please don't include pictures of code or JSON in your question. Instead replace them with the actual code and JSON as text. Having the code and JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: i edited my post with the code.